# Remove/drop current commit within interactive rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I'm in an interactive rebase and have marked the commits on which I need to have a closer look with `edit` (`e`) now while looking into the commits I realize that some of the commits need to be dropped/removed. Which is the correct commit to do that within the interactive mode?

Currently I perform the following commands:

```
$ git reset HEAD^
$ git checkout -- <File> # <- here I list all of the files that need to be reset
$ git rebase --continue # this complains that I have to perform git commit --allow-empty or git reset
# since I don't want the empty commit I do …
$ git reset
$ git rebase --continue
```

This is very lengthy. So I tried

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
$ git rebase --continue
```

But that produces a merge conflict.

So what is the easiest way to drop the current commit, when beeing in the edit mode of an interactive rebase?

Answer (score 2):

> So what is the easiest way to drop the current commit, when beeing in the edit mode of an interactive rebase?

For me, the *easiest* way, by far, is to make a note of the commit I want to drop (subject line and any other identifying marks), finish the interactive rebase, and start a new interactive rebase and mark the commit as "drop".  There is no need to do it all at once!

Answer (score 0):

If you `git reset --hard` you are also losing the changes of the current commit, hence the conflicts I suppose. Instead you could do a mixed reset with

```
git reset HEAD^
```

And amend the last commit with the changes in the current commit:

```
git add your_changes
git commit --amend -m "new commit message"
```